# Indentación (sangría) en Ada

Tags: ada

Hola buenas estoy realizando un par de ejercicios en lenguaje Ada, pero siempre me sale esto, se que es por la indentación, pero no sé si son tabulaciones, espacios...

¿Podríais ayudarme a entender como se realizan en este lenguaje?

He intentado poner solo una tabulación

> (style) horizontal tab not allowed

Comment: Será posible que dependa del editor en el que estás intentando construir el código esté validando la indentación? En GNAT GPS, por ejemplo, hay que ir a `Preferences > Editor > Ada > Default indentation setting` para decirle que use tab o espacio.

Comment: El caso es que estoy usando vim, visual studio code, como editores de texto, y me dan esos problemas. ¿Cómo lo arreglo? GNAT GPS, me resulta muy complicado de manejar. @Alfabravo

Comment: Pues tanto VisualStudio (usas VisualAda o algún plugin?) como Vim deben apuntar a GNAT... lamento no poder ayudar más, pero no conozco mucho del lenguaje y el entorno. Es lo que he encontrado